# Cached faster autocomplete, tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

When I'm trying to type in tags, and select tags that already exist, I find the autocomplete a little slow.

It would be nice if the autocomplete was cached locally.  I don't think it matters if the tag-name(**number-with-tag**) gets stale - as long as you can quickly see the tag exists and a rough count.

Comment: meh, fast enough for me..

Comment: How fast should it be? It's not a life and death thing...

Comment: @alex, every time I see a new tag, I will kill a puppy. How do you feel now?

Comment: @Downvoter excellent! My plan for cat domination is working purrrfectly!

Answer (score 4):

> It would be nice if the autocomplete was cached locally.

That's non-trivial. You could do it with HTML 5 client-side storage (available to a minority of users) or Gears (separate install, deprecated). Then you'd need to keep the lists in sync. And, as others have pointed out, it's not too bad already.

Perhaps it could be optimized further, but caching locally is like regex -- "Now you have two problems."

Comment: "minority of users"? It's implemented by firefox, opera, safari, chrome and even Internet Explorer (starting from version 8)!

Comment: The "minority" bit is out of date, but just by a couple months: http://gs.statcounter.com/ IE 7 + 6 + old Fireox is still 35% of common browsers.